# Does using the program stack involves syscalls?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I'm studying operating system theory, and I know that heap allocation involves a specific syscall and I know that compilers usually optimize for this requesting more than needed beforehand.

But I don't find information about stack allocation. What about it? It involves a specific syscall every time you read from it or write to it (for example when you call a function with some parameters)? Or there is some other mechanism that don't involve syscall perhaps?

Comment: You seem to be conflating *"stack allocation"* with *"using the program stack"*.  Machine instructions such as PUSH, POP, CALL, and RTN are typically implemented for CPUs that use a stack.  You simply do not use a *"syscall"* to execute common machine instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Typically when the OS starts your program it examines the executable file's headers and arranges various areas for various things (an area for your executable's code, and area for your executable's data, etc). This includes setting up an initial stack (and a lot more - e.g. finding shared libraries and doing dynamic linking).

After the OS has done all this, your executable starts executing. At this point you already have memory for a stack and can just use it without any system calls.

Note 1: If you create threads, then there will probably be a system call involved to create the thread and that system call will probably allocate memory for the new thread's stack.

Note 2: Typically there's "virtual memory" (what your program sees) and "physical memory" (what the hardware sees); and in between typically the OS does lots of tricks to improve performance and avoid wasting physical memory, and to hide resource limits (so you don't have to worry so much about running out of physical memory). One of these tricks is to allocate virtual memory (e.g. for a large stack) without allocating any actual physical memory, and then allocate the physical memory if/when the virtual memory is first modified. Other tricks include various "swap space" schemes, and memory mapped files. These tricks rely on requests generated by the CPU on your program's behalf (e.g. page fault exceptions) which aren't system calls, but have similar ("ask kernel to do something") characteristics.

Note 3: All of the above depends on which OS. Different operating systems do things differently. I've chosen words carefully - e.g. "Typically" means that most modern operating systems work like I've described (but "typically" does not imply that all possible operating systems work like that; and some operating systems do not work like I've described).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ok, then the stack manipulation doesn't require syscalls like the heap does...But...Maybe is a silly question, but if both the heap and the stack are part of a process "virtual memory" linear space, then why we have it designed in such a way that heap requires syscalls and the stack no?

Comment: @Hawky: That's an astute observation (not a silly question at all). When virtual memory is pre-allocated at executable start-up; the OS has no idea when previously used/modified virtual memory is no longer being used, which causes OS to think the data is still needed when it isn't (clogging up things like swap space, etc). For stack this isn't a problem because stack is relatively small (several MiB) and the access pattern implies it's likely that previously used memory will be re-used again. Heap is relatively large (e.g. maybe several GiB) and the access pattern is a lot more random.

Comment: @Hawky: However; there's no real reason why a huge amount of virtual memory can't be pre-allocated for heap at executable start-up; and then the heap inform the OS that freed heap memory is no longer used via. a syscall (where the OS knows that the data itself can be discarded even though the virtual memory remains allocated). In this way heap could have no syscalls for allocation (but would still have a syscall for freeing heap and "discarding data but not freeing" virtual memory).

Answer (score 1):

No, stack is normal memory. For process point of view, there is no difference (and so the nasty security bug, where you return a pointer to a data in stack, but stack now is changed.

As Brendan wrote, OS will setup stack for the process at program loading. But if you access a non-allocated page of stack (e.g. if your stack if growing), kernel may allocate automatically for you a new stack page. (not much different as when you try to allocate new memory in heap, and there is no more memory available on program space: but in this case you explicitly do a syscall to tell kernel you want more heap memory).

You will notice that usually stack go in one direction and heap (allocated memory) in the other direction (usually toward each others). So if you program need more stack you have space, but if you program do not need much stack, you can use memory for e.g. huge array. Or the contrary: if you do a lot of recursion, you allocate much stack (but you probably need less heap memory).

Two additional consideration: CPU may have special stack instruction. But you can see them as syntactic sugar (you can simulate PUSH and POP with MOV. CALL and RET with JMP  (and simulated PUSH and POP).

And kernel may use a special stack for his own purposes (especially important for interrupts).

Comment: Thanks for the info! A question that comes to my mind with this is...then if for example im coding in C, when the compiler translates to machine level instruction...It uses the CPU level stack manipulation instructions that you mention? I suppose they will fill specific registers in the CPU with the stack information...And then when the OS has to do a context switch to other thread...It just stores that register in the PCB or something?

Comment: Mmm now that I think better of, the stack should be in RAM...So the CPU PUSH and POP instructions for example maybe operate directly on RAM? And now that I think better of it, then when a context switch occurs, it is not part of the state the OS has to context switch, because is stuff in RAM, part of the image process...

Comment: CPU has a register which store the actual position of the stack (see it as a stack pointer). PUSH will copy the value of operant to the stack, and it update the stack position (1, 2, 4 bytes, according the operand). [POP is the inverse]. A compiler increment the stack position, so that it can use the stack for local variables. [And CALL is just saving the position of next instruction into the stack and just to function. RET will read from the stack the position of next instruction. As you see, you may use a different register and explicit CPU instruction (or having two stacks, etc.)